# Which is better/quicker .append("<div></div>") or .append($("<div>",{})

Tags: jquery

I am making some divs using jquery. Some divs use information from a database so I have used  .append($("",{}) to create them. There are some however that are simple and so I have been using .append("Example Text"). If the data is static and no XSS chances then which is better/quicker?

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mybutton").click(function(){
        $("#testdiv").append("<div>Example text 1</div>");
        $("#testdiv").append($("<div>",{text:"Example text 2"}));
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="mybutton">Append Button</button>
    <div id="testdiv"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: If performance is a concern, ditch jQuery and just do `document.getElementById('testdiv') .appendChild(document.createElement('div')) .appendChild(document.createTextNode('Example text'));`

Comment: If there is a speed difference, it would be very negligible. Go with the one that best suits your needs. As you say you use the second option when you need to add more data to the element, but the first when little to no data is needed.